Define a new command with the same effect as \quad \text{...}
I have a tex file
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem,fullpage,microtype}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\TT}{\mathbb{T}}
\setlist{font=\normalfont}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{assumption} \label{main_assmpt1}
There exist constants $C>0, \alpha \in (0, 1), \beta \in (0, 1)$ such that for $t \in \TT$ and $x, y \in \RR^d$:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(A\arabic*)]
\item $\nu$ has a density $\ell_\nu \in C^\alpha_b (\RR^d)$.
\item $a_t$ is invertible.
\end{enumerate}
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem}
Let \cref{main_assmpt1} hold. Then ...
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
We have
\[
1 > 2 \quad \text{by \cref{main_assmpt1}[A1]}
\]
\end{proof}

\end{document}

in which I use \quad \text{...}. I would like to ask how to define a new command \qtext{...} that brings the same effect. Thank you so much for your elaboration!

\newcommand\qtext{\quad\text}

@DavidCarlisle Thank you so much for your solution! Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

You just need a simple alias command such as
\newcommand\qtext{\quad\text}

